# Problems While Scraping with VBA - VBA Web Scraping

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping

I'm trying to get a number from a static page in a website, but when I do the HTML request, the result is a strange HTML without the informations of the original html that I want.

The website that I'm trying to get the information is:
https://fnet.bmfbovespa.com.br/fnet/publico/exibirDocumento?id=233361&cvm=true
but I can get the same result with:
https://fnet.bmfbovespa.com.br/fnet/publico/visualizarDocumento?id=233361&cvm=true

The number that I want to get is the number "0,05" in the page

My code is:

```
Sub trying()
Dim html As HTMLDocument
Set html = New HTMLDocument
With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
    .Open "GET", "https://fnet.bmfbovespa.com.br/fnet/publico/exibirDocumento?id=233361&cvm=true&", False
    .setRequestHeader "If-Modified-Since", "Sat, 1 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT" 'to deal with potential caching
    .send
    html.body.innerHTML = .responseText
End With
Set element = html.getElementsByTagName("td")(31).innerText
Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, 1) = element    
End Sub
```

I have also tried to do that using the InternetExplorer.Application but the the problem keeps the same

Comment: Please read "[ask]", "[Stack Overflow question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648)", "[mre]" and their linked pages. When asking a question about scraping we need the smallest amount of HTML and code necessary to run and duplicate the problem _in the question itself_.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After trying a bunch of request headers, `Accept` request header is required to return the response in HTML:

```
Sub trying()
    Dim html As HTMLDocument
    Set html = New HTMLDocument
        
    With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        .Open "GET", "http://fnet.bmfbovespa.com.br/fnet/publico/exibirDocumento?id=233361&cvm=true&", False
        .setRequestHeader "Accept", "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9"
        .send
        html.body.innerHTML = .responseText
    End With
    
    Dim element As String
    element = html.getElementsByTagName("td")(32).innerText
    Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, 1) = element
End Sub
```

Comment: This header solved my problem, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Just add a `.htm` (or `.html`) extension to the request to specify file type wanted.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub trying()
    Dim html As MSHTML.HTMLDocument
    Set html = New MSHTML.HTMLDocument
    
    With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        .Open "GET", "https://fnet.bmfbovespa.com.br/fnet/publico/exibirDocumento.htm?id=233361", False
        .send
        html.body.innerHTML = .responseText
    End With
    Debug.Print html.querySelector("tr:nth-child(6) .dado-valores").innerText
End Sub
```

---

Alternatives, that are a little more effort, include adding the accept header or base64 decoding the `.responseText` before writing to `.innerHTML`.

If you went down the less preferable base64 decode route, using function from [here](https://www.codegrepper.com/code-examples/vb/excel+vba+base64+decode) (note: pretty sure this is not the original source), then you will need to amend the following line:

```
 .DataType = "bin.base64": .Text = Replace$(b64, Chr$(34), vbNullString) 'modified line
```

---

```
Public Function DecodeBase64(b64$)
    Dim b
    With CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM").createElement("b64")
        .DataType = "bin.base64": .Text = Replace$(b64, Chr$(34), vbNullString) 'modified line
        b = .nodeTypedValue
        With CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
            .Open: .Type = 1: .Write b: .Position = 0: .Type = 2: .Charset = "utf-8"
            DecodeBase64 = .ReadText
            .Close
        End With
    End With
End Function
```