# Base64 decode XML VBA

Tags: xml, vba, base64

I'm trying to base64 decode an XML file in VBA, but get this error when using this function:
[image]

That function works to decode normal text strings but when trying to decode XML file with it, I get that error. Anyone have any ideas what I should modify to get this to work?

```
Function Base64Decode(ByVal vCode)
    Set oNode = 
    CreateObject("Msxml2.DOMDocument.3.0").CreateElement("base64")
    oNode.dataType = "bin.base64"
    oNode.Text = vCode
    Base64Decode = oNode.nodeTypedValue
    Set oNode = Nothing
End Function
```

Comment: Do you encode the file in discussion? Using the same function like for text files? If not, I am afraid that not the decode function is problematic, as it is... Maybe its encoding is the problem.

Comment: Is it possible that the XML file to contain any UTF-8 characters?

Comment: @FaneDuru I encoded it by using powershell:
$cmd =@'
xml pasted here
'@
[Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::Unicode.GetBytes($cmd))

Comment: Try encoding/decoding using "ADODB.Stream" and "Microsoft.XMLDOM". I will post the functions. I am not their father, I found them sometime on the internet...

Comment: Try the function in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70197064/15597936)

Comment: @RaymondWu I tried that one but doesn't seem to work and gives this error
https://imgur.com/NS1vxn5

Comment: @user2697001 Which line did the error occured? Are you also able to provide a sample encoded xml? Lastly you should always post your code in the question as text, not in images.

Comment: @RaymondWu It happens on line 18 here https://pastebin.com/J5SEUCak . In this case, I still got a normal string to decode but feels like that should work also before I use the base64 decode function to decode the XML.

Comment: Please edit your question and and paste the code in, your code isn't long so it should fit in properly. Try `sh = Base64Decode("dwBzAGMAcgBpAHAAdAAuAHMAaABlAGwAbAA=")`. It should return a string so I don't think you should use `Set` statement.

Answer (score 1):

Please, try using the next functions to encode/decode:

```
Function EncodeBase64(text$)
    Dim b
    With CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
        .Open: .Type = 2: .Charset = "utf-8"
        .WriteText text: .Position = 0: .Type = 1: b = .Read
        With CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM").createElement("b64")
            .DataType = "bin.base64": .nodeTypedValue = b
            EncodeBase64 = Replace(Mid(.text, 5), vbLf, "")
        End With
        .Close
    End With
End Function

Function DecodeBase64(b64$)
    Dim b
    With CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM").createElement("b64")
        .DataType = "bin.base64": .text = b64
        b = .nodeTypedValue
        With CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
            .Open: .Type = 1: .Write b: .Position = 0: .Type = 2: .Charset = "utf-8"
            DecodeBase64 = .ReadText
            .Close
        End With
    End With
End Function
```

Comment: How would I encode my XML using that function? Not sure how I would store the multi line XML stuff in VBA. That's why I used powershell oneliner since it's really easy to use and encode